# SQL: one of two datetime values with same format is incorrect while other is correct

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Trying to insert single line into DB:

```
INSERT INTO ok_users 
( email
, password
, name
, phone
, address
, group_id
, last_ip
, created
, remind_code
, remind_expire) VALUES 
( "test@test.com"
, "asdasdsasda"
, "szusalmeitiwzchGP zwusalmeznqzdqbGP"
, "000"
, "test, "
, "30"
, "127.0.0.1"
, "2019-03-31 03:00:00"
, null
, null)
```

and receives following error:

```
1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-31 03:00:00' for column 'created' at row 1, Time: 0.000000s
```

If I change date to `2018-03-30 03:00:00` it will work.

Could anyone help me understand why?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using, and what is the data type for your `created` column? Another question is what is the value returned by `SELECT @@sql_mode;`

Comment: Daylight time saving in your location(Ukraine) -Sunday, 31 March 2019, 03:00:00 clocks were turned forward  and 2018 Sunday, 25 March, 03:00

Comment: The problem is that for 2019-03-31, doesn' t exist the 3 am because of the summer time change

Comment: Incidentally, is `"test, "` correct?

Comment: *"Daylight time saving in your location(Ukraine) -Sunday, 31 March 2019, 03:00:00 clocks were turned forward"* that still would not explain why `2019-03-31 03:00:00` isn't correct @P.Salmon i would understand that datetimes after `2019-03-31 03:00:00` would be incorrect based on the server locale like `2019-03-31 03:00:00.00001` or `2019-03-31 03:00:01` .. i wonder what happens when the topicstarter uses `2019-03-31 02:59:59` instead in this insert..

Comment: 2019-03-31 02:59:59 will pass @RaymondNijland. Looks like that is the issue: field format was timestamp not datetime as I expected. After changing it to datetime it worked.

Comment: *"Looks like that is the issue: field format was timestamp not datetime as I expected. After changing it to datetime it worked."*  Ok great i was trying to [reproduce](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ajny8FK79GBzqv9dhmmr4b/0) but i was not getting the error you got..  Seams your OS locale seams to be causing that issue on the TIMESTAMP datatype..